# Create Multiple Line Items with Add to Cart Form

Tags: commerce

I am selling "TablesFor8" at an event, and would like to make it possible for the individual purchasing a "TableFor8" to specify names and food choices of the 8 individuals who will sit at that table.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which Commerce version? They differ quite a lot. Commerce 2 for Drupal 8 has support for this out of the box. See the documentation https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/displaying-products/add-to-cart-form#add-fields-for-customizable-products

Comment: And Drupal 7/Commerce1 has an add-on module for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question, I am running Commerce on Drupal 7.  Then, thanks for this, but I figured it out.  What I ended up doing was creating a custom line-item type for "Tables for 8" and including a multi-value field [Name, Meal Choice] on that line item type.  That, coupled with a little CSS allowed me to create a form [I actually used Views-Accordion to make that form appear as a dropdown] that allowed Tables for 8 purchasers to enter the names and meal choices of their guests.

Easy peasy, once you know how to do it!